# Access token exception instagram with working access token?

Tags: scala, httprequest, httpresponse, access-token, instagram

I'm having trouble with an HTTP Request from my scala code.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/training?access_token=workingaccesstoken
```

gives

```
{"meta":{"code":200},"data":{"media_count":872874,"name":"training"}}
```

which is what I want.

When I try to do this from my code like:

```
val data = WS.url("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/training?access_token=sameworkingtoken").get()
val body = data.get().getBody()
```

gives

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"OAuthParameterException","code":400,"error_message":"\"client_id\" or \"access_token\" URL parameter missing. This OAuth request requires either a \"client_id\" or \"access_token\" URL parameter."}
```

Which is not what I want.
I'm tired and dont know what am I doing wrong here? Should I go for some other solution? I'm stuck and would really appreciate some answers for my problem. 
BTW. I'm doing my request from local, maybe this is my problem?
Thanks!

Comment: What library are you using for the http request?  It appears that your access_ token param is not being sent but I can't say for sure unless I know what lib that is.

Comment: uhm, did you think of like my import of play.libs.WS? @cmbaxter

Comment: My http get request is returning a promise. Can this be making trouble? If it is done asynchronosly?

Answer (score 0):

When I ran this code, I got an exception indicating that the access token was not valid (expected).  If you plug in a valid token it should work:

```
import play.api.libs.ws.WS
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object WSTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val data = WS.url("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/training?access_token=sameworkingtoken").get()
    val resp = Await.result(data, 5 seconds)
    println(resp.body)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I try this I get a type mismatch, saying that when passing `data`in `Await.result()` it found a Promise[Response] but want an Awaitable[?].